# Python script not running on web server

Tags: php, python, web, interface

I am trying to call a python script from a php script. When I run the PHP script in the linux command prompt, the python gets executed properly. But when I run the php script on the web server, the python script isn't executed. Can anyone tell me why this is so and what I can do to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can run it from linux command,because the system has python interpret.
So I think you should check whether the server support interpret python.
(i.e.some server may support asp instead of php for same reason)
```

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you for your reply. The script runs fine if run on linux command. But I need to run it from the web server. I am using php to upload files to the web server and then use python to parse those files. So after upload the python script to parse the files needs to be called.Any idea how can I do it from web interface?

Comment: Hi Alex, can you also tell me how to configure web server to be compatible with python? Am I supposed to edit my php.ini file?

Comment: @user3704113 first you have to find whether you have full rights of the server. If you buy a virtual server which doesn't support python,then nothing you can do about it.If you have full rights,then check this http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your answer. I can run it from linux command instead of triggering from web interface as you mentioned.